# How do I display a float value in a WinForms label?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have to write code for Convert `int` to `float`, It has converted but value not shown in the label,

```
    private void Btn1ConvertIntToFloat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal i;
        float f;
        i = 10;
        f = (float)i;// Convert.ToSingle(i);
        label1.Text = string.Format("Int value 10 is converted to :{0} ", f);  
    }
```

Comment: It is showing value ... what is the actual problem ?

Comment: No It Was Not Showing Label But Now Showing...Thanks For immediate Reply...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while formatting string you will have to use below code.

```
label1.Text = string.Format("Int value 10 is converted to :{0:0.00} ", f);
```

You can find more formatting options on 
http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Comment: Really Thanks For Your Answer And immediate Reply Thanks...It Was Worked.I got Float Ans In Labels...

Comment: Thanks, You can mark answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx).

You are correct that the cast to `float` is successful, but when displaying it back to the user you're not specifying a format for the value.  Try something like this:

```
private void Btn1ConvertIntToFloat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal i;
    float f;
    i = 10;
    f = (float)i;
    label1.Text = string.Format("Int value 10 is converted to :{0:F2} ", f);  
}
```

The `{0:F2}` specifies that you will print the floating point number of `f` to 2 decimal places.

Comment: Really Thanks For Your support And immediate Reply,I have changed   But This error Shown                                                                                                         "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll....

Additional information: Format specifier was invalid.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, try F2 instead

Comment: Yes Now It working With F2 Thanks a lot.....